# How Do I Remove The Right Hand Block On The Main Header?

Tags: customization, menus

I want to expand the main header across the full width of the page. Currently, the surrounding colour block around the text box, seems to stretch above the top menu bar on the right, and it looks irregular. So I need to expand the main header across, which therefore includes the top menu bar. I am using Wordpress Twenty Fourteen.

Answer (score 0):

The Twenty Fourteen theme uses `max-width` to limit the content and header. You can navigate to **Appearance** > **Customize** > **Additional CSS** and add in the following CSS:

```
.site,
.site-header {
    max-width: none;
}
```